# Extract element of list by name

Tags: r

I have this kind of list `q` which consist of two types of data `q[1:20]`:

```
$id
[1]    28    12    18 10751
$name
[1] "Action"    "Adventure" "Drama"     "Family"   
$id
[1] 28 12 53
$name
[1] "Action"    "Adventure" "Thriller" 
$id
[1] 12 28 53
$name
[1] "Adventure" "Action"    "Thriller"
```

I wand extract only names in this style:

```
[1] "Action"    "Adventure" "Drama"     "Family"
[2]"Action"    "Adventure" "Thriller"
[3] "Adventure" "Action"    "Thriller"
```

When I used following `q[1:20]$name` code it returned only the first line

```
[1] "Action"    "Adventure" "Drama"     "Family"
```

and I couldn't get all the `name` values.
How can I extract all names from this list?

Comment: If you have a `list` then use `q$name` or `q[['name']]`.  It is not clear what you want to get.  Please show the example using `dput`.  If there are multiple elements with `name` and want to extract all of them `q[names(q)=='name']`  or to group them `split(q, names(q))`

Comment: Could you provide a reproductible exampple using `dput`please

Comment: thank you when I used  split(q, names(q)) I got what I wand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to extract all `name` elements, create a logical `vector` based on the `names` and subset the 'q' `list`

```
q[names(q)=='name']
```

The `list` can also be grouped in to nested `list` based on the `names` by `split`ting

```
split(q, names(q))
```